# Mislabeling of Kosher food

Tags: kashrut-kosher

This question is regarding the mislabeling of treif as kosher, by food producing companies.

It happens every so often that we see the OU, OK etc. put out a msg saying that their kosher symbol was used without permission by a certain food producing company.

My questions are:

1. How much of a halachic liability does a Jew carry when he eats a non-Kosher food that was mislabeled?
2. Does he need to repent for this? ( As far as the Jew is concerned, he did his due diligence by making sure that the food product had a proper kosher symbol; so he should be 0% liable which would mean zero repentance, shouldn't he?).
3. How often are we supposed to call a kosher certifying agency to make sure that a product is not mislabeled? Lets say you drink a can of coke every 2 days. So are you supposed to call the OU every 2 days to make sure that the can of coke was not mislabeled?

Comment: Other than meat, I imagine that in the vast majority of cases, the mislabeled product is rabbinically prohibited. At which point we fall back on the famous Nesivos -- a shogeg on a derabanan doesn't require teshuva. As to your last point, don't be OCD about this. The agencies send out alerts, which kashrut.com aggregates (and you can even get via email). If you are reasonably connected to the Jewish world, it's a reasonable assumption that you'd hear about a problem in a major product, soon enough. Just don't be willfully blind.

Comment: @Shalom Is that opinion of the Nesivos widely accepted? My impression is that it is not.

Comment: @N.T. I've never heard otherwise, and I *have* heard several significant instances where the Nesivos was invoked. Ask anyone from Ner Israel during the R' Ruderman era about "the delicious pareve ice cream" story. Rabbi Yaakov Hopfer of Baltimore shlit"a, a major, major *moreh hora'ah* on taharas hamishpacha, told about a case he got where the Nesivos applied as well.

Comment: @shalom Bl"N I will ask.